# How can I compile opencv library components manually?

Tags: c++, opencv, gcc

I was to compile only couple of source files from opencv library manually. 
I used the command

`gcc -g -L/usr/local/lib -I /usr/local/include/opencv -o main ../src/testVideo.cpp ~/development/opencv/opencv2.4/modules/core/src/convert.cpp 'pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs'`

But it gives me errors saying include files are not found. All my include files are in /usr/local/include which is in my path.

Comment: `convert.cpp` requires `precomp.hpp` which is in the same folder, therfore you need to add this folder to your include path too. This file again needs a lot of other files. Since you don't just include the final library but the single files you need to have all the single folders in your include path. `/usr/local/include/opencv` will just contain the library headers for outside use, not for all the internal header files

Comment: Great! It worked! `gcc -g -L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/include/opencv2/ -I/home/harsh/development/opencv/opencv/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_lnx/include -I/usr/include/eigen3/ -o main ../src/testVideo.cpp ~/development/opencv/opencv2.4/modules/core/src/convert.cpp 'pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs'`